# Teams Toolkit Local Enviorment issue

Tags: azure-active-directory, teams-toolkit

I am trying o debug my team's app locally as I have done since starting development by clicking the debug(Chrome) in the team's toolkit extension. Starting today I have been getting the following error:

`[RegisterBot.AlreadyCreatedBotNotExist]: Could not get bot with id 65e9a59e-3b1b-4605-97bd-9a8000243bc0 which was created before. This could happen if the bot was created by another account. Visit https://aka.ms/teamsfx-switch-account-or-subscription-help to learn more.`

I have not been logged into any other account so I'm unsure how this has happened. Has this been an issue for anyone else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The live-site issue was resolved. @koiram Can you try again to check if the issue is gone? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's some live-site issue of the underlying server side APIs.
You can try the workaround below. For more details, check https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx/issues/7184.

> Hi all, here is a workaround for VS Code:
>
> 1. In `.vscode/tasks.json`, remove "Set up bot" from the "dependsOn" field of "Start Teams App Locally" task.
> 2. From command palette, run "Tasks: Run Task" and select "Start local tunnel". Then open "Start local tunnel" terminal, you can see the
>    forwarding url like
>    "https://f633-2404-f801-9000-18-6fec-00-26d.ngrok.io".
> 3. Create an AAD app with your M365 account. Create a client secret and copy the secret value which will be used later.
> 4. Create a bot in https://dev.botframework.com/bots/new with your M365 account. Set the messaging endpoint using the above forwarding
>    url like
>    "https://f633-2404-f801-9000-18-6fec-00-26d.ngrok.io/api/messages".
>    After the bot is created, configure Microsoft Teams channel.
> 5. In `templates/appPackage/manifest.template.json`, update `botId` to the AAD app client id; update `validDomains` to the domain of the
>    above forwarding url like
>    "f633-2404-f801-9000-18-6fec-00-26d.ngrok.io".
> 6. In `bot/.env.teamsfx.local`, update "BOT_ID" to the AAD app client id; update BOT_PASSWORD to the AAD app client secret.
> 7. F5.